# Why do we guess for unknown coefficients with $\alpha\sin x$ using the form $\alpha \sin x + \beta \cos x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

It seems slightly unintuitive why we use the form $\alpha \sin x + \beta \cos x$ to guess for a particular integral, of say, the form $\alpha \sin x$ as opposed, to say, $\alpha \sin x$, while things like guessing $ax^2 + bx + c$ for a linear particular integral sounds more intuitive. Can someone explain where this comes from other than the fact that it works out?

Comment: Your guess should include any derivatives of the function. Have you tried to solve a DE with that guess? Try to find a particular solution of $y' + y = \sin(x)$ and it will be extremely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\sin x$ contains two different exponential terms, $\sin x = \frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$. This forces the guess (for a real solution) to have the form $ce^{ix}+\bar ce^{-ix}=2Re(ce^{ix})$ and in real functions this is $α\sin x+β\cos x$.